# Error1055: incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by MySql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysqlprocedure, mysql-procedimiento

He probado mi respuesta junto con la de mi profe y en los dos casos al llamar al procedimiento nos da el mismo error de  ***incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by MySql*.**
Por qué sucede esto y como podría solucionarlo.

> 1.Codifica un procedimiento que muestre el nombre de cada departamento y
> el número de empleados que tiene.

```
delimiter $$
drop procedure if exists ejer7; $$
create procedure ejer7()
    begin
    declare Vnombre varchar(14);
    declare cantidad int;
    
    select DNOMBRE, count(*)
    into Vnombre, cantidad
    from DEPART D
    join EMPLE E on E.DEPT_NO=D.DEPT_NO
    group by D.DEPT_NO;
    
    select concat("EL departamento ", Vnombre, 
    " tiene ", cantidad, " empleados.");
    end;
$$

call ejer7();
```

**Tabla Empleados**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Tabala Departamento**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias.

Comment: Cuando escribes consultas con `GROUP BY` debes indicar al SGBD cómo deben agruparse aquellas columnas que no serán únicas en ese conjunto de resultados. Puedes hacer poniendo una función de agregación: `MAX(), MIN(), GROUP_CONCAT()`... o añadiendo la columna en la lista en el `GROUP BY`. Esto ocurre porque el SGBD se pregunta: *en el grupo hay resultados de varias filas, ¿cuál quieres que te muestre de todos?*